# How I can put a variable into variable in PHP OOP?

Tags: php, oop

My code is like that

```
class Some extends Another {
    var $first = "Hello";
    var $second = "Hello";
}
```

I want to put `$first` to `$second` so how I can put it?
I try something like the following

```
class Some extends Another {
    var $first = "Hello";
    var $second = "Hello $first";
}
```

but I got the following errors

```
syntax error, unexpected '"'
```

And it's that possible to put?

Comment: Side note, typo in extends in `class Some extnds Another`

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Comment: read this http://www.php.net/manual/en/keyword.class.php

Comment: you miss spelled `extnds`. make it `extends`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is in the fine manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you can reference class members like that - you would have to set up `$second` in the constructor:

```
class Some
{
    public $first = "Hello";
    public $second;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->second = "Hello {$this->first}";
    }
}
```

Though a more realistic way to approach this particular example would be like so:

```
class Some
{
    public $first = 'Marty';

    public function getSecond()
    {
        return "Hello {$this->first}";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class Some extends Another {
    var $first = "Hello";
    var $second = "Hello $first";
}
```

This results in error, because, you cannot use the result of an expression to initialize a property in an object, only a static value can be used. If you wanted to do something like your example, you'd have to do it in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

```
$first = "hello1";
$second = "hello2";
$second = "hello2".$first;
echo $second;
```

Explanation is if the value of first variable is needed to be appended to the second variable it is done like that means string value then dot and then the first variable without quotes.

Comment: Please give some explanation, not just code...